# I want to create a macro that eliminates a lot of repetitive (specific) clicking and typing

Tags: python, scripting, macros

I would like to be able to load and interact with (type into fields, click buttons, etc) an in-house program. The program itself is within our company (the exact details, I'm not going to disclose). This program needs to be ran frequently, and not always at the same time. A lot of the clicking and navigating the program is exactly the same every time, with the only real change being the text in a single text box.

To help clarify, my example would be an icon that looks like Google Chrome. For this example, lets assume my FaceBook password is actually a Google Authenticator code that changes all the time. When I click this 'Google Chrome' icon, it would ask me for the current password, then proceed to open up Google Chrome, navigate to Facebook.com, then enter my credentials with the supplied password.

Is there any library I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have to use Python? There are languages/toolkits specifically developed for this kind of thing, like AutoIt or AutoHotkey on Windows, and Automator on Mac.

Comment: Agreed, something like AutoIt is designed to do this and using Python would make the problem significantly harder.